# How to restrict ScrollView's boundaries in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I have a registration screen in my app but it looks bad on phones with a small screen. The main problem is I want to restrict the ScrollView boundaries to scroll the form on the picture (now it is not scrollable on the left picture). I want this form to be never able to get higher than the toolbar or lower than the button. Everything that doesn't fit the boundaries should be cut.

[image: Nexus 5, bad layout]
[image: Nexus 5, bad layout #2]

The layout itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/action_bar_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/action_bar_background"
            android:minHeight="40dp"
            android:theme="@style/toolbar_theme"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/tool_bar_text_color">

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/action_bar_toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="User Registration"
                android:textColor="@color/tool_bar_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/action_bar_title_text_size" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbarSize="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/submit_btn"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/action_bar_toolbar">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/first_name_layout"
                    style="@style/MaterialTextInputLayout"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/text_field_width"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:hint="@string/wizard_sign_up_first_name"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/action_bar_toolbar">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/first_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <!-- 6 more similar elements -->

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/submit_btn"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/default_button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/default_button_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:text="@string/wizard_sign_up_submit"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: make the scrollView height 0dp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add ScrollView **`android:layout_height="0dp"`**.

> Using 0dp, which is the equivalent of "MATCH_CONSTRAINT"

```
 <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:scrollbarSize="100dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/submit_btn"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/action_bar_toolbar">
```